# Inequality for Fourier Transform of Indicator Function

Tags: integration, inequality, fourier-analysis

If $A\subset [0,1]$ is measurable, then is it true that $|\int_0^11_A(x)e^{2\pi i x}dx| \le 1/\pi$, where $1_A(x)$ is the indicator for $A$?  Can someone provide a reference (and/or correction)?

**Motivation/Background:** For $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{C}$ there is always a subset $A\subset [n]$ for which $\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k}|\le |\sum_{k\in A}^{}x_k|$.  I think that the integral inequality above can be used to show that $1/\pi$ is the best possible constant that makes the above statement true for all subsets $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\subset \mathbb{C}$, by taking $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{x_k}$ to be approximately the uniform distribution on $S^1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks.  That was the motivation for thinking it was true, after all.

Comment: @N.S. What do you mean by "$y$"?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I missread the question, thought it is about the FT not about the FT at $y=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof of the stronger estimate
  $$ \Big |\int_A e^{2\pi ix} \,dx \Big| \le\frac1\pi\sin(\pi\mu), $$
where $\mu$ is the measure of $A$.

It is convenient to work with the symmetric interval $[-1/2,1/2]$. We have 
\begin{align*} 
  \Big |\int_A e^{2\pi ix} \,dx \Big|^2 
    &= \Big| \int_A \cos(2\pi x)\,dx + i\int_A \sin(2\pi x)\,dx\Big|^2 \\ 
    &=\Big( \int_A \cos(2\pi x)\,dx \Big)^2 + \Big( \int_A \sin(2\pi x)\,dx\Big)^2.
\end{align*}
Write $\mathrm{mes}(A)=2c$.

Since $\cos(2\pi x)>\cos(2\pi c)$ if $|x|<c$, and $\cos(2\pi x)<\cos(2\pi c)$ if $c<|x|<1/2$, we have
  $$ 1_A(x)(\cos(2\pi x)-\cos(2\pi c)) \le 1_{[-c,c]}(x) (\cos(2\pi x)-\cos(2\pi c)) $$
for all $x\in[-1/2,1/2]$. Integrating, we get
\begin{align*} 
  \int_A \cos(2\pi x)\,dx - 2c\cos(2\pi c) 
    &\le \int_{-c}^c\cos(2\pi x)\,dx - 2c\cos(2\pi c) \\
    &= \frac1{\pi} \sin(2\pi c)  - 2c\cos(2\pi c);
\end{align*}
that is, 
  $$ \int_A \cos(2\pi x)\,dx \le \frac1{\pi} \sin(2\pi c). $$
Indeed, this inequality is true for *any* set $A$ of measure $2c$. Applying it to the set $A+\alpha$ with a fixed parameter $\alpha$, we get
  $$ \frac1\pi\sin(2\pi c) \ge \int_A \cos(2\pi x-2\pi\alpha)\,dx = C\cos(2\pi\alpha) + S\sin(2\pi\alpha), $$
where $C=\int_A \cos(2\pi x)\,dx$ and $S:=\int_A \sin(2\pi x)\,dx$. To optimize, we choose $\alpha$ so as to have $\cos(2\pi\alpha)=C/\sqrt{C^2+S^2}$ and $\sin(2\pi\alpha)=S/\sqrt{C^2+S^2}$. This gives
  $$ \Big |\int_A e^{2\pi ix} \,dx \Big| = \sqrt{C^2+S^2} \le\frac1\pi\sin(2\pi c), $$
as wanted.

Comment: How do you have the first identity in your response (the squared integral equal to the sum of the two squares)?

Comment: @StefanLafon: I've made an edit to address your question.

Comment: This is great thanks.  That's a nice argument.  I think the last paragraph can be simplified by noting that for some $\alpha$, $|\int_A e^{2\pi i x}dx| = \int_A e^{2\pi i (x  + \alpha)}dx = \int_A \cos(2\pi (x + \alpha))dx = \int_{A+t}\cos(2\pi x)dx \le \frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi m(A))$ (where $A+t$ is a circular shift in $[-1/2,1/2]$) by the previous argument.  It's essentially the same though, so it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I'll accept this soon if nobody else posts anything.  Do you know of any references containing similar inequalities or to anything else that uses the same proof technique?

Comment: @user3281410: Yes! I learned it from this paper: http://emis.matem.unam.mx/journals/INTEGERS/papers/a24int2005/a24int2005.pdf

Comment: For anyone who reads my earlier comment, $t$ was a typo.  I meant to type $\alpha$, but I can no longer edit it.

Comment: @user3281410: reciprocally, are there any references to the inequality you mention in your question ("For $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{C}$ there is always a subset $A\subset [n]$ for which $\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k}|\le |\sum_{k\in A}^{}x_k|$")?

Comment: @W-t-P I only know it as one of the problems from "The Cauchy Schwarz Master Class" by Michael Steele.  It's at a very elementary level, but it's fun & has some nice material.  The inequality is just a problem in the book, without much background.  It has a hint that you should consider $A$ to be a set of the form $\{k | \langle x_k,\theta\rangle \ge 0\}$.  Taking a sup over $\theta$ and using the fact that the sup will be bigger than the average, you get this inequality.

Comment: @W-t-P I checked and he cites "W.W. Bledsoe (1970)" and "Mitrinovic (1970 pg 331)," but I haven't looked at these references.